# BeautifulSoup <b>bold</b> tag fail

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a html that contains:

```
<b>
<p align="left">TXT1</p>
</b>
<p align="left">
<b>NR1</b> 
<b>TXT2</b>
TXT3 
<b>TXT4</b>
TXT5
</p>
```

When I do:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = urllib.urlopen('url')
htmlr = html.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlr)

print soup
```

I get something different:

```
<p align="left">TXT1</p>
<p align="left">NR1 <b>TXT2</b> TXT3 <b>TXT4</b>
TXT5</p>
```

I am analyzing html document layout, so losing tags is quite frustrating. Why is it happening and whats the best way to stop it? Help much appriciated!

EDIT: I need to handle the badly formed html documents for information extraction purposes. If their creator wanted some text to be rendered bold, I have to take it into account, even if the person created an invalid html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<p>` inside a `<b>`. BeautifulSoup is attempting to perform error recovery (as do browsers).

The best way to stop it is to [fix the HTML](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: @root — Your browser is recovering from the error in a different way to BeautifulSoup. Fix the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Tidy appears to correctly repair the invalid HTML. They have a web implementation of it here: http://infohound.net/tidy/

I entered:

```
<b><p>hello world</p></b>
```

and got this result:

```
<p><b>hello world</b></p>
```

There appears to by a python version here:
http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxExperimental/mxTidy/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) instead of BeautifulSoup. Html5lib implements the HTML5 parser algorithm, so it should result in producing the same DOM as a modern browser does.

Disclaimer: I've not tried the html5lib parser for myself, so I don't know it's current stability level.

Comment: You can also use Beautiful Soup 4, which allows you to parse a document with html5lib and then use the Beautiful Soup API on the resulting data structure.

Answer (score -1):

Same As quentin suggested.

If you want the `<p>` element to be bold then use inline CSS instead of `<b>` tag.

```
<p style='font-weight:bold;' align="left">TXT1</p>
<p align="left">
<b>NR1</b> 
<b>TXT2</b>
TXT3 
<b>TXT4</b>
TXT5
</p>
```

Comment: I am not creating these documents. I need to read structured text out of them!